# Custom iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am making a library using the data structure: `std::vector<std::string>`. I have to satisfy the API, which says that in order to iterate through my data structure users would have to do the following:

```
for (lib::result::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
```

There are two ways I could do this, implement `lib::result::const_iterator` on my own or inherit from `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`, they should both work. I have read that inheriting from the vector iterator is a bad idea.

I have decided to use Boost iterator facade, is this a good idea?
Also, I am having trouble implementing  `increment()`. If I have a pointer to a string in an std::vector, how do I point to the next string?

Lastly, my implementation could change from `std::vector<std::string>`, to `std::vector<MyDatatype>`, so I would like to use the boost facade so if ever I decide to make changes to my data structure, things would be easier.
Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to inherit, just `typedef` it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace lib {
  struct class {
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
  };
};
```

If you change the underlying type, assuming that the iterator is compatible with the `std::vector<std::string>` iterator, just change the typedef.  If it isn't compatible with the `std::vector<std::string>` iterator, you are breaking your API.  However, this really is a problem for another day.

If you do need to implement an iterator, boost's "iterator adaptor" is a good choice: wrap the `std::vector<std::string>` iterator with yours.

"iterator fascade" would be something I might use if I had to generate a stable binary interface over library version changes.  In that case, my "iterator facade" would forward to a `pImpl`-type `virtual` interface (which repeats the methods that "iterator facade" requires from its implementation) that implemented each feature of the facade.  The internal `pImpl` implementation would then forward the methods to the `std::vector<std::string>` in a way similar to how "iterator adaptor" works.  But in almost all cases, this is overkill.

But the first case -- where you typedef `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` -- is both the most efficient and easiest to implement.

Comment: "facade". (Yes, the 'c' is pronounced 's'.)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the vectors iterator:

```
class MyClass
{
     typedef std::vector<std::string>  MyData;

     MyData    data;

     public:
         typedef  MyData::iterator       iterator;
         typedef  MyData::const_iterator const_iterator;

         iterator       begin()       {return data.begin();}
         const_iterator begin() const {return data.begin();}

         .... etc
```